# IEEE in-text citation with page number

Tags: citation-style, ieee

Is the syntax used in this [tex.stackexchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292708/73051) valid?

The asker wants to cite a specific page in a single reference and uses the format:

> Some assertion [1, p. 23].

Meaning reference number 1 and page 23 of that document.

Comment: What do you think might be wrong with it?

Comment: @user2768 I have never seen it before. Some sources differ on the syntax. For example reference 1 and page 23 might be displayed like [\[1: 23\]](https://libguides.sait.ca/ieee/in-text).

Comment: `\cite[info]{key}` is standard LaTeX. You can put what you like for `info`, e.g., you may use \S1, where 1 is the section number; pp1-3, where 1 is the first page and 3 is the last page; p1, where page 1 is the only page; some other style. Your choice of journal may specify some precise usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the syntax used in this tex.stackexchange answer valid?

Yes